# MTLTextureDescriptor has height greater than the maximum allowed size error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, metal

I am getting the error

`-[MTLTextureDescriptorInternalvalidateWithDevice:], line 1325: error 'Texture Descriptor Validation MTLTextureDescriptor has height (8334) greater than the maximum allowed size of 8192'`

when trying to run my SpriteKit game on an iPhone 13 mini. This causes the game to crash on both simulator and physical device. When I test it on an iPhone 13, however, the game run fine.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

The size of my SKScene's are all 1284 x 2720.

Comment: Simulator supports only a very limited feature set, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a bug. According [The Metal Feature Set Tables](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Feature-Set-Tables.pdf):
All iPhone 13 models support 2D texture with resolution up to **16384 px**